# ViewController does not conform to protocol xyzDelegate

Tags: swift, delegates

```
// QuizPopUpViewController.swift
@objc protocol QuizPopUpViewControllerDelegate {
    func ApplyNowToSendBack()
}

class QuizPopUpViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITextViewDelegate {
    weak var delegate: QuizPopUpViewControllerDelegate?
}


// giving event from here
 if isError == false {
     self.delegate?.ApplyNowToSendBack() // delegate method
    }
}

// Another Viewcontroller     
class ShortlistViewController: ParentViewController , QuizPopUpViewControllerDelegate {

}
```

When i add `QuizPopUpViewControllerDelegate` to `ShortlistViewController`, i get the following error:

> Type "ShortlistviewController" does not conform to protocol QuizPopUpViewControllerDelegate

Comment: Hi Pravin. You might wanna have a look at stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and try to improve your question in order to get more and better answers.

Comment: Sure but I am learning, how to use Stackoverflow and swift as well..could you please help me for my question

Answer (score 0):

The problem is exactly what the error description is suggesting. You need to make your class conforming on `QuizPopUpViewControllerDelegate` delegate.

To do so, you need to declare the function, what is in `QuizPopUpViewControllerDelegate`.

```
   // Another Viewcontroller     
   class ShortlistViewController: ParentViewController , QuizPopUpViewControllerDelegate {
          func ApplyNowToSendBack() {
            // do something with the callback.
          }
    }
```

To avoid asking such questions in the future, i would recommend to read more about the [delegate pattern in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html).